# Report last login by user on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

What would be the easiest way to get a report on Google Analytics containing authenticated users ordered by the last login time (the latest login first)?

We are already using Event logging with Category "User", Action "Login" and Label set to user ID (a GUID). Is it possible to base the report on this data?

---

UPDATE 5-Dec-2018:

As a reference, we have a Custom Report for top logins:

[image]

This shows:

[image]

Now, I would like to change 'Hits' to "the last time the event occurred", with the given Event Label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom report with the event label ordered by date and time. Though the default implementation in GA only gives you up to the hours I believe. If you want more granularity, I think you'd need to create a custom dimension with a timestamp to the second/millisecond and capture that data front-end.

Comment: I did not find any option for ordering the event label by date and time. I updated the current Custom Report to Question.

Comment: Here's a list of all the time dimensions in GA, https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=time

Comment: Ok, it is possible to add Time/Date dimension to Dimensions and then order by this field. The user is shown for each day (s)he has logged in, so not just last login. I guess this is not possible on the web interface. I would need to get the data via GA api and format it with a tool of my own, which is an overkill for this particular case.